# excel-vba Single column to multidimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put values of a column's range in a 2-dim array (0 To 1, 0 To ´length of my column's range`).

I need something like this:

```
arr(0, 0) = value of B4
arr(1, 0) = value of B5
arr(0, 1) = value of B6
arr(1, 1) = value of B7
...
arr(0, n) = value of Bn
arr(1, last row of my column range) = value of last B
```

Can someone tell me what function i must use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code loops through each cell in Column B, starting at B4, and assigns their values to the array aResults, as you've described...

```
Dim aResults() As Variant
Dim rRange As Range
Dim nCols As Long
Dim i As Long

Set rRange = Range("B4:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

nCols = rRange.Cells.Count \ 2
nCols = nCols + (rRange.Cells.Count Mod 2)

ReDim aResults(1, nCols - 1)

For i = 0 To rRange.Cells.Count - 1
    'Debug.Print i Mod 2, i \ 2, rRange(1).Offset(i).Value
    aResults(i Mod 2, i \ 2) = rRange(1).Offset(i).Value
Next i
```